# replace set of strings in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using `$('div#top_container').html()`, I get the following as an example:

```
<div class="top" id="top_container">
    <div class="example">First</div>
    <div class="example">Second</div>
</div>
```

giving...

```
<div class="example">First</div>
<div class="example">Second</div>
```

Here, using `.replace()`, I want to replace `<div class="example">` with `*%^%` (random set of characters) and remove `</div>`:

```
var content = $('div#top_container').html();                
var clean_1 = content.replace('<div class="example">','*%^%'); //add $*!#$
var clean_2 = clean_1.replace('</div>',' '); //remove </div>
```

giving...

```
console.log(clean_2); --> *%^%First*%^%Second
```

Now, the number of `example` div elements can vary and I need to first find out how to target them all. Also is there a cleaner way to target both `<div class="example">` and `</div>` at the same time?

**EDIT:**

I am not looking to change the html itself, but rather have the edited version as a variable that I can do stuff with (such as send it to php via ajax).

How would I do this?

Comment: I am not sure about your specific requirement of replace, but instead of replace its better to get the div's values (e.g. First, Second etc.) and concat them using '*%^%'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method with a callback and generate prefered text string by getting text content using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text) method.

```js
$('div.example').replaceWith(function(v) {
  return '%^%' + $(this).text();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="example">First</div>
  <div class="example">Second</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE:** If you don't want to update the original element then use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and do the remaining thinks on the cloned element.

```js
var res = $('#parent')
  // clone element
  .clone()
  // get element with `example` class
  .find('.example')
  // update content
  .replaceWith(function(v) {
    return '%^%' + $(this).text();
  })
  // back to previos selector and get html content
  .end().html();

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="example">First</div>
  <div class="example">Second</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that `.replaceWith` changes the element itself. I am looking to have it as a variable and not alter the html (I should have been more clear in the question). I will update the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you =) Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replaceWith` function

```
$(function () {
   $(".example").replaceWith(function(){
     return "%^%"+$(this).text();
    });
});
```

You can make a clone of container if you don't want to change original div.

```
var html="";
$(function () {
 var newHtml = $("#top_container").clone();
 $(newHtml).find(".example").replaceWith(function () {
   html+= "%^%" + $(this).text();
   });
});

console.log(html);
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Create one prototype like :

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (toReplace, replaceWith){
    return this.split(toReplace).join(replaceWith);
}
```

and your jquery code be like :

```
  $("div#top_container").each(function( i ) {debugger;
    console.log(this.innerHTML.replaceAll('<div class="example">','*%^%').replaceAll('</div>',' ');)
  });
```